# Cannot use Dapper.Dll - Framework 4.8

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dapper

Dealing with a really frustrating issue. I'm unable to make use of the Dapper package in my .NET 4.8 project within Visual Studio 2019.

I've tried a myriad of solutions such as clearing nuget cache, downgrading project to 4.6.1, trying different versions of the Dapper package but to no avail.

The package appears to be 'installed' but if I attempt to make use of it I get the following error

Error in the build is;

```
    Metadata file 'C:\git\Panmure.Compliance Portal\Source\packages\Dapper.2.0.90\lib\net461\Dapper.dll' could not be found CRMCentralDataService   C:\git\Panmure.Compliance%20Portal\Source\CRMCentralDataService\
```

Packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Dapper" version="2.0.90" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

Appreciate any other recommendations or solutions to try out!

Comment: @MitchWheat that's only a lower bound; it should work fine on net48; however, this *sounds* like a broken local nuget cache; honestly, I'd be tempted to just delete the `Dapper.2.0.90` folder, do a package restore, and see if it works any better!

Comment: @benbants just to be clear: is this the first time you've tried Dapper, or did something break when we released 2.0.90 a few days ago (but it was fine before that)?

Comment: FWIW; I've almost completely forgotten how to to correctly configure old-style package refs; does this work in a new dummy console exe? how complex is the csproj, and is it even remotely feasible to migrate to SDK-style projects? the tooling works a *lot* better, honestly (you can just create a .NET Core project somewhere, and then just change the `<TargetFramework>` to `net48`, and: you're done - that's an SDK-project targeting .NET Framework 4.8; then you can use `<PackageReference>` etc)

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for the quick response! This project has used Dapper for some time and has worked fine, issue has only appeared with the update.

Comment: @MarcGravell Project isn't too complex tbf so I could try that, I'm going to try your first suggestion however as I too believe it's something as silly as that!

Comment: @MarcGravell attempted first suggestion, same issue. Second suggestion, created the new project as stated and changed TargetFramework to net48 and installed Dapper, still no luck!

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm assuming this must be a missing hidden dependency or maybe a broken install of .NET on my pc?

Comment: honestly, I don't know what is happening; if you have access to another machine, it would be worth trying there to see if it is repeatable; I don't *think* it is a dependency thing - we haven't added/removed any; do the files that I've listed appear? if not: where are you pulling nuget packages from? meaning: is it simply that package restore is failing, perhaps because of a network problem (for me, this usually means my VPN has dropped, since I usually access nuget packages via an internal corporate relay server)

Comment: BTW: did you know that you can download a package from nuget, change the file extension to .zip, unzip it, and: that's (more or less) the file tree? meaning: you can get the files I've listed in my answer directly from the nupkg

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't that's good to know! I've just done it and I have all the same files. Trying to get another Developer to try and load the project and see if they've got the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it should "just work"; locally, I set up a .NET Framework 4.8 project with old-style csproj and packaged.config, and: it works fine:

[image: Example showing old-style csproj working just fine with Dapper]

Obviously it throws with a `NullReferenceException`, but: that `NullReferenceException` *came from inside Dapper*:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 2808
>
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 572
>
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 443
>
> at Program.Main() in C:\Users\marc\source\repos\ConsoleApp45\Program.cs:line 9

So; I don't think anything is *inherently broken in the package*; I think something very odd is happening in your build/deployment, though.

Under my test project, I have:

- packages

  - Dapper.2.0.90

    - .signature.p7s
    - Dapper.2.0.90.nupkg
    - Dapper.png
    - lib

      - net461

        - Dapper.dll
        - Dapper.xml
      - net5.0

        - Dapper.dll
        - Dapper.xml
      - netstandard2.0

        - Dapper.dll
        - Dapper.xml

If you don't have the same... that's related to the problem.